# MSBuild unable to find directory in Azure cloudservice csdef file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, msbuild, visual-studio-2015

I have a cloud project with two web roles set up in a directory structure like this :

```
C:\myWork\myProject\
                    Solution.sln
                    \CloudService\CloudService.ccproj
                    \WebRole1\WebRole1.csproj
                    \WebRole2\WebRole2.csproj
```

My cloud service .csdef is :

```
<ServiceDefinition name="CloudService" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition" schemaVersion="2015-04.2.6">
  <WebRole name="WebRole1" vmsize="Small">
    <Sites>
      <Site name="WebRole1" 
            physicalDirectory="..\..\..\WebRole1\publish\_PublishedWebsites\WebRole1">
        <Bindings>
          <Binding name="http" 
                   endpointName="http" 
                   hostHeader="WebRole1.cloudapp.net" />
        </Bindings>
      </Site>
      <Site name="WebRole2" 
            physicalDirectory="..\..\..\WebRole2\publish\_PublishedWebsites\WebRole2">
        <Bindings>
          <Binding name="http" 
                   endpointName="http" 
                   hostHeader="WebRole2.cloudapp.net" />
        </Bindings>
      </Site>
    </Sites>

    -snip-
```

When I package the CloudService project in VS2015, the package creates fine with both WebRoles built and within the package as expected. It uploads to Azure and both WebRoles are active and error free.

However, if I build with MSBuild through the command line :

```
msbuild /t:corepublish;package /p:visualstudioversion=14.0;targetframeworkversion=4.5;roletargetframework=4.5;config
uration=debug
```

I receive the following error during CorePublish :

```
    CorePublish:
      CorePublish: PackageWebRole = True
      Publishing starting...
      RolePlugins       is 
      Importedmodules is 
      Publishing to 'Publishapp.publish\'
      Creating directory "Publishapp.publish\".
      TargetServiceDefinition is Publish\ServiceDefinition.csdef
      TargetServiceConfiguration is Publish\ServiceConfiguration.cscfg
      Roles is 
    C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Windows Azure Tools\2.6\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.targets(3003,5): warning : CloudServices68 : No TargetFrameworkVersion specified for role WebRole1. Using .NET framework v4.0 for packaging. [c:\mywork\myproject\CloudService\CloudService.ccproj]
    c:\mywork\myproject\CloudService\Publish\ServiceDefinition.csdef : error CloudServices079: Cannot find the physical directory 'c:\mywork\WebRole1\publish\_PublishedWebsites\WebRole1' for virtual path WebRole1/. [c:\mywork\myproject\CloudService\CloudService.ccproj]
    Done Building Project "c:\mywork\myproject\CloudService\CloudService.ccproj" (Publish target(s)) -- FAILED.
    Done Building Project "c:\mywork\myproject\Solution.sln" (Rebuild;Publish target(s)) -- FAILED.
    Done Building Project "c:\mywork\myproject\cloudservice\cloudservice.ccproj" (corepublish;package target(s)) -- FAILED.
```

As you can see, MSBuild is looking for WebRole1 here : `c:\mywork\WebRole1` whereas it should be looking here : `c:\mywork\myproject\WebRole1`.

So why is packaging the cloud service working inside VS2015, yet not with MSBuild ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue, and in my case I had to update the MyProject.Azure.ccproj file so that it was always prefixing the PublishPath with the $(ProjectDir). It was not doing that for TFS build originally. I made them the same for now. Not entirely sure if the example I got [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/davidhardin/2013/01/18/building-and-packaging-virtual-applications-within-azure-projects/) is even relevant anymore.

Before:

```
    <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(PublishDestinationPath)'=='' and '$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)'=='true' ">
  <!-- When Visual Studio build -->
  <PublishDestinationPath>$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)</PublishDestinationPath>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(PublishDestinationPath)'=='' ">
  <!-- When TFS build -->
  <PublishDestinationPath>$(OutDir)</PublishDestinationPath>
</PropertyGroup>
```

After:

```
    <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(PublishDestinationPath)'=='' and '$(BuildingInsideVisualStudio)'=='true' ">
  <!-- When Visual Studio build -->
  <PublishDestinationPath>$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)</PublishDestinationPath>
</PropertyGroup>
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(PublishDestinationPath)'=='' ">
  <!-- When TFS build -->
  <PublishDestinationPath>$(ProjectDir)$(OutDir)</PublishDestinationPath>**
</PropertyGroup>
```